# MongoDB & Java : Retrieve records ordered by an index

Tags: java, mongodb, kotlin

So I am pulling records from my MongoDB, but I want them to be coming back from the database in order from an Index.

So I want records where "proc" = 0 and sorted by "level", lowest first.  It feels like the code below is getting x amount of records from inserted order, then sorting them.

```
val mongoClient = MongoClients.create(Mongo)
val database = mongoClient.getDatabase(Database)
val urlsCollection = database.getCollection(Urls)

val findQuery = Document()
findQuery.append("proc", 0)
val cursor = urlsCollection.find(findQuery).sort(Document("level", 1)).iterator()
```

In the DB, I have an index called proc_1_level_1

```
{
    "proc" : 1.0,
    "level" : 1.0
}
```

Comment: Yes. if you add some query find(findQuery) then Mongo will no longer be able to use your index to sort query results and will be forced to sort it on the fly.

Comment: what is the outout you are getting for the below query in mongo shell db.Urls.find({"proc": 0}).sort({"level": 1}).explain("executionStats");

Comment: @GovindParashar, that's not correct. See [Sort and Non-prefix Subset of an Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-and-non-prefix-subset-of-an-index). As @Mani has mentioned, please provide the output of the query explain, and MongoDB server version. Also, could you clarify what do you mean by `it feels like the code below` i.e. how do you know ?